# A die is thrown, The first 1, 2 or 3 is the random variable $Y$. Find the variance of $Y$.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

A loaded six-sided die has the following probability function:

$P(X = 1) = P(X = 3) = P(X = 5) = \frac{1}{9}$ ,

$P(X = 2) = P(X = 4) = P(X = 6) = \frac{2}{9}$  .

The die is tossed repeatedly until the outcome is 1, 2 or 3.

The first 1, 2 or 3 is the random variable $Y$. Find the variance of $Y$.

What I did:

$P(X=1,2 ,3)= \frac{4}{9}$

$Y$ ~ $Geometric(\frac{4}{9})$ , So, $Var(Y)= \frac{q}{p^2} = \frac{5/9}{(4/9)^2}=\frac{45}
{16}$

But the Answer to this question is $0.5$. Kindly Explain.

Comment: The problem is very poorly phrased...but nothing in the statement suggests that $Y$ is the trial number for the first occurence of $1,2$ or $3$.  I think $Y$ is literally $1,2$ or $3$, depending on which one you see first.  That variable does, indeed, have variance $\frac 12$.

Comment: I still don't understand even if Y is 1 2 0r 3 how does variance come out to be half.

Comment: Well, just work it out.  You should see that $Y= \{1,3\}$ with probability $\frac 14$ (each) and $P(Y=2)=\frac 12$.  Now just compute the variance.

Comment: okay thankyou I got it.